# Convert vba to c# - please help! Lotus Notes create new email

Tags: c#, email, vba, lotus-notes

I have working VBA code, but I can't convert it to C#.
I have tried, but my C# skills are failing me.

The code below creates new message and opens new email in Lotus Notes (using active session if Lotus application is active) OR opens a new instance of Notes if Notes is not running.

Could you please assist?

```
Sub SendMail()
Dim Notes As Object
Dim db As Object
Dim WorkSpace As Object
Dim UIdoc As Object
Dim userName As String
Dim MailDbName As String
Set Notes = CreateObject("Notes.NotesSession")
userName = Notes.userName
MailDbName = Left$(userName, 1) & Right$(userName, (Len(userName) - InStr(1, userName, " "))) & ".nsf"
Set db = Notes.GetDataBase(vbNullString, MailDbName)
Set WorkSpace = CreateObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
Call WorkSpace.ComposeDocument(, , "Memo")
Set UIdoc = WorkSpace.currentdocument
Recipient = "test@email.com"
CCD = "test2@email.com"
Call UIdoc.FieldSetText("EnterSendTo", Recipient)
Call UIdoc.FieldSetText("EnterCopyTo", CCD)
Subject1 = "Subject")
Call UIdoc.FieldSetText("Subject", Subject1)
Call UIdoc.GotoField("Body")
Call UIdoc.INSERTTEXT("This text goes to body")
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Set UIdoc = Nothing
Set WorkSpace = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
Set Notes = Nothing
END SUB
```

Thank you!

Thank you competent_tech for solution:

```
    public void SendMail() 
{ 
    dynamic Notes = null; 
    object db = null; 
    dynamic WorkSpace = null; 
    dynamic UIdoc = null; 
    string userName = null; 
    string MailDbName = null; 
    Notes = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Notes.NotesSession")); 
    userName = Notes.userName; 
    MailDbName = userName.Substring(0, 1) + userName.Substring(userName.Length - ((userName.Length - (userName.IndexOf(" ", 0) + 1)))) + ".nsf"; 
    db = Notes.GetDataBase(null, MailDbName); 
    WorkSpace = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")); 
    WorkSpace.ComposeDocument("", "", "Memo"); 
    UIdoc = WorkSpace.currentdocument; 
    Recipient = "test@email.com"; 
    CCD = "test2@email.com"; 
    UIdoc.FieldSetText("EnterSendTo", Recipient); 
    UIdoc.FieldSetText("EnterCopyTo", CCD); 
    Subject1 = "Subject"; 
    UIdoc.FieldSetText("Subject", Subject1); 
    UIdoc.GotoField("Body"); 
    UIdoc.INSERTTEXT("This text goes to body"); 
    UIdoc = null; 
    WorkSpace = null; 
    db = null; 
    Notes = null; 
}
```

Comment: Does that code work? I've never head of `Nothin`.

Comment: Just add a COM reference to whatever component DLL `Notes.NotesSession` is in and let Visual Studio generate the wrapper for you. I *think* it's `domino.dll`, but it's all a faint memory now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to be roughly:

```
    public void SendMail()
    {
        dynamic Notes = null;
        object db = null;
        dynamic WorkSpace = null;
        dynamic UIdoc = null;
        string userName = null;
        string MailDbName = null;
        Notes = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Notes.NotesSession"));
        userName = Notes.userName;
        MailDbName = userName.Substring(0, 1) + userName.Substring(userName.Length - ((userName.Length - (userName.IndexOf(" ", 0) + 1)))) + ".nsf";
        db = Notes.GetDataBase(null, MailDbName);
        WorkSpace = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace"));
        WorkSpace.ComposeDocument("", "", "Memo");
        UIdoc = WorkSpace.currentdocument;
        Recipient = "test@email.com";
        CCD = "test2@email.com";
        UIdoc.FieldSetText("EnterSendTo", Recipient);
        UIdoc.FieldSetText("EnterCopyTo", CCD);
        Subject1 = "Subject";
        UIdoc.FieldSetText("Subject", Subject1);
        UIdoc.GotoField("Body");
        UIdoc.INSERTTEXT("This text goes to body");
        UIdoc = null;
        WorkSpace = null;
        db = null;
        Notes = null;
    }
```

It would be better if you had the com object that you could add as a reference, but there could be versioning issues there. Also note that this code assumes late binding.

Comment: WorkSpace.ComposeDocument(null, null, "Memo"); needs to be WorkSpace.ComposeDocument("", "", "Memo");  THANK YOU! Solved!

Comment: That's excellent news. Since it resolved your question, can you click on the checkmark next to the answer to let future visitors to this question know that this solved your answer? I have updated the answer with your change.

Comment: @Andrew - Let me show my appreciation by not clicking the huge check mark that is prominently displayed!